# YouTube Api Standalone Player results

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I use `YouTube Api v3`.And I  use `Standalone player` to start new `Activity` with some video.

```
holder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx,
                    Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
                    appearance,
                    100,     //after this time, video will start automatically
                    true,               //autoplay or not
                    true);             //lightbox mode or not; show the video in a small box
            ctx.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I wonder, if  there is some  way to some  result  of  starting video and  it's finishing (maybe  some  `onDestroy`  method  of `StandaloneActivity`)  and  how can  I use it?

As I know, it  good  be  possible  with others `players`  provided  by `Youtube Api`, but I'd to know about `Standalone` one exactly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. 
You should replace startActivity(intent) to startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_INTENT_CODE), and then override in your Activity method `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == YOUR_INTENT_CODE){
        //do your stuffs here
    }
}
```

Standaloneplayer is an activity, and, as any activity, can be started for result, so the calling activity will receive a callback when the result is received.

Comment: Никита Хлебушкин, спасибо